# When would you use Servlet init params?

Tags: java, servlets, parameters, web.xml, init

I was reading about Initialization Parameters for Servlets on [this blog post](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-servlets/web-xml.html#initParams) by Jenkov.

It made me wonder though, when would I ever need to initialize variables this way? 
If I wanted to predefine certain values, why not just do it with fields in the Java code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be useful if your servlet was packaged in a jar for use by another user, who could then set the input parameters to their own specification in their own servlet definition. If you hard coded it, they could not otherwise 'configure' your servlet.

Comment: This is a great example for `DispatchServlet` from Spring MVC and `FacesServlet` from JSF.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Can you explain why?

Comment: @Imray it is easily to understand when you work with any of these frameworks or another web mvc framework for Java.

Answer (score 1):

Because if you need to change those variables, one requires the editing of web.xml and restarting of the servlet, and the other (your suggestion) requires the recompilation of the application.

Comment: Ah, I was only thinking of myself. But I suppose in a team it makes much more sense